# How to toggle icon when slot is active

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm using a Vuetify v-menu to display a choice of country.  Next to the v-chip title is a down chevron.  When I click the chip to activate the menu, I want the chevron to change to an up chevron. I want to toggle the v-icon when the slot is active.  I've tried various flavors and I could swear I got this code off a working project.  But the icon never changes.

```
<template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
  <v-chip label v-on="on" class="mr-2">
    U.S. CANADA &amp; CROSS BORDERS
    <v-icon right v-if="on">mdi-chevron-up</v-icon>
    <v-icon right v-else>mdi-chevron-down</v-icon>
  </v-chip>
</template>
```

If on is the event, how do I get at the isActive property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`activator` has another property called value which is boolean :

```
<template v-slot:activator="{ on,value }">
  <v-chip label v-on="on" class="mr-2">
    U.S. CANADA &amp; CROSS BORDERS
    <v-icon right v-if="value">mdi-chevron-up</v-icon>
    <v-icon right v-else>mdi-chevron-down</v-icon>
  </v-chip>
</template>
```